# Center an absolute div vertically?

Tags: html, css

I have a div which is a small modal that opens in the center of the screen.
It used to be `fixed` positioned but since fixed is **not supported by mobile** browsers, I made it `absolute`.

When a user scrolls down, this modal position will be wrong because it scrolls with the page as expected. I need the `fixed` behavior.

How to make sure that no matter how much down did I scroll, the modal stays in the middle ?

```
.whiteBox{
  visibility: hidden;
  position:absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 94vw;
  height: auto;
  background-color:  rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
  left: 100vw;
  top:7%;
  border-radius: 4vw;
  opacity: 0.0;
  transition: all 0.55s ease;
  z-index: 1000;
 }

 .whiteBox.show{
    left: 3vw;
    opacity: 1.0;
    visibility: visible;
 }
```

The body is `relative` positioned.

One option I was considering is adding on JS the scrollTop to his `top` style. But since it's animated from right to left, the animation will look bad if I add the top position dynamically.

```
div.style.top=50+document.body.scrollTop +"px";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution , to anyone who is struggling on mobile :

When user scrolls i would like to reposition ALL modals so they are ready for animation, so when scrolling is stopped i update their top position.

```
 window.onscroll = function() {adjustmodals()};

 var isScrolling = null;
 function adjustmodals() {

        window.clearTimeout( isScrolling );
        isScrolling = setTimeout(function() {

         //lop all modals
          for (key in menuBox){
            var div = document.getElementById(key);
            console.log(div);
             div.style.top=50+document.body.scrollTop +"px";
          }

         }, 66);
}
```